# mongoose query array as an arg of Promise.all doesn't seem work properly

Tags: express, mongoose, promise, ecmascript-6

I'm working with express and mongoose, having problem.

As an API server, I implemented a router js file. One of posts is to save four objects in db at once.

As I know, mongoose query function like save() can be used as a promise object.

So I attended to make a mongoose query array, and put it into Promise.all as an argument, but It doesn't work. (I can't find any records on db after run this code.)

following is my code, please review it and teach me why it doesn't work.

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import Collection from '../models/collection.model';

const router = new Router();

router.post('/api/collections/basic-pick/:userId', (req, res) => {
  const pickedMons = req.body.pickedMons;
  const collections = [];
  let condition = 1;
  for (const mon of pickedMons) {
    condition = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
    const collection = new Collection({
      _monId: mon._id,
      _userId: req.params.userId,
      condition,
    });
    // this log prints right objects
    console.log('collection: ' + collection);
    collections.push(collection);
  }
  const proms = [];
  for (const collection of collections) {
    // collection.save() function returns promise, right?
    proms.push(collection.save);
  }
  Promise.all(proms).then(() => {
    return res.json({ success: true });
  });
});

export default router;
```

Comment: I have found the answer. I had to change the code 'prom.push(collection.save)' to 'prom.push(collection.save())'. Now it works.

Comment: Glad you found the answer. So as you know by now, `save()` is a method used in working with collections in MongoDB and like all methods you need the parens. You should post your answer so others can benefit. I also recommend utilizing test driven development.